Prove inequality
Let $a, b, c, d$ non-zero positive real numbers, and $a+b+c+d=4$, then prove that
$$(ab+cd)(ac+bd)(ad+bc)\leq8 \tag{1}$$
I understand that, equation holds, when $a=b=c=d=1$
And then I tried use , and grouping by
$$a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2 \geq 2(ab+cd)$$
$$a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2 \geq 2(ac+bd)$$
$$a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2 \geq 2(ad+cb)$$
And multiplying all 3 I have similar part with left side of my inequality (1). So, I have
$$(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^3 \geq 8(ab+cd)(ac+bd)(ad+cb) \tag{2}$$
So, my question is how I can simplify left side of (2)?

Hint: apply the inequality $$3\sqrt[3]{xyz}\le x+y+z $$

Do you know RMS $\geq$ AM
Thus applying that in a, b, c, d
$\sqrt{\frac{a^{2} + b^{2} + c^{2} + d^{2}}{4}} \geq \frac{a+b+c+d}{4}$
$\frac{a^{2} + b^{2} + c^{2} + d^{2}}{4} \geq 1$
$a^{2} + b^{2} + c^{2} + d^{2} \geq 4$
$(a^{2} + b^{2} + c^{2} + d^{2})^{3} \geq 64$
Now since the $a^{2} + b^{2} + c^{2} + d^{2}$ has the minimum value of 64, we can replace it in the inequality (2) you have made.
Therefore $64 \geq 8(ab + cd)(ac + bd)(ad + cb)$
Finally $8 \geq (ab + cd)(ac + bd)(ad + cb)$
HENCE PROVED
